# Moving Large Amounts of Data to Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, ftp, windows-server-2012, iis

I have a physical server right now with a repository of many gigabytes of media files I need to move to a new virtual machine that will act as my new web server. However, I am not sure what is the best way to move such large amounts of data in a remote environment. What is best practice? One idea was to set up an FTP server on my virtual machine to do a one-shot transfer. Is this a good idea? Or should I divide my data into chunks?

Both machines are running Windows Server 2012 as the OS and have IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way to transfer huge amounts of data is by physical means,
meaning via a physical external disk.

If that is not an option, then FTP is as good as any other.
To protect yourself against disconnection, use an FTP client that can resume
a broken upload so as not to restart from scratch.

Here are a couple of such free FTP clients :

- [Core FTP LE](http://www.coreftp.com/)
- [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/index.php)